# PageFlip - Change page on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using a pageflip effect from this this site [link](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?9yQO5MGv)

i have add control buttons to go to the next and previous page.

what i want to do now is on keydown arrow right and left to change the page.

is it possible?

i tried with this code:

**Javscript:**

```
(function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.exemples:eq(0)').flippage({
                        width: 1160,
                        height: 755
                    });

                    $('.exemples:eq(1)').flippage({
                        width: 1160,
                        height: 755
                    });
                });
                $(window).bind('keydown', function(e){

                    if (e.keyCode==37)
                        $('.exemples:eq(0)').flippage({
                        width: 1160,
                        height: 755
                    });
                    else if (e.keyCode==39)
                        $('.exemples:eq(1)').flippage({
                        width: 1160,
                        height: 755
                    });

                });
            })(jQuery);
```

**my next and previous buttons:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('previous'); return false;">PREV</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('next'); return false;">NEXT</a>
```

Hope that anyone can help me with this.

thanks in advance

**UPDATE** tried this way (still not work):

```
(function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.exemples:eq(0)').flippage({
                        width: 1160,
                        height: 755
                    });

                    $('.exemples:eq(1)').flippage({
                        width: 1160,
                        height: 755
                    });
                }); 
                $(window).bind('keydown', function(e){

                    if (e.keyCode==37)
                        $('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('previous'); return false;             
                    });
                    else if (e.keyCode==39)
                    $('.exemples:eq(1)').trigger('next'); return false;

                    });                     
                });
            })(jQuery);
```

Comment: your key down need to use this: $('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('previous'); and $('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('next');

Comment: have try it.. but still not work.. have update my code. take a look pls.. i don´t know if i miss something or i do something wrong.. thanks for the post

Comment: depends on which one you are trying to turn the page of. as you have 2 flipbooks you will also need to find out where the cursor is and do an if based on which one they want to turn the page of

Comment: @Pete: thanks for your interest and for the post.. maximus have write a perfect code for my issue... now is solved

Comment: The answer below does exaclty the same as the answer I provided (but with an extra link click) - I think you just got your syntax wrong - looking at your code above, your if statements don't have opening and closing curly brackets `{}` and you have pasted the return false in there for some reason

Comment: yes Pete, you are right.. and thanks for your answer.. i got always the wrong sintaxe.. i copy the return false only to test it, because wasn´t working and have tested a lot of things, and then i only copied the last code i tested..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around,

```
<a id="prev" href="#" onclick="$('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('previous'); return false;">PREV</a> 
<a id="next" href="#" onclick="javascript:$('.exemples:eq(0)').trigger('next'); return false;">NEXT</a>
```

and

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 37)
   { 
    $("#prev").trigger('click');             
   }
   else if (e.keyCode == 39)
   {
     $('#next').trigger('click');
   }                     
});
```

Comment: works great..!! yeah.. thank you very much for this.. one thing you forget the "#" to define the prev id... but all works fine now. great help ==> +1